# how to write data into one csv file?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, export-to-csv

I am currently trying to write data from firebase into a csv file. It sort of works but I get three different files and I don't know how to fix this. I am just highly confused at this point of time.

Do you have any idea on how to fix this mess?

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "records" : {
    "id1" : {
      "2020-08-11 15:40:13" : {
        "0" : "5"
      },
      "2020-08-11 16:35:09" : {
        "0" : "18"
      }
    },
    "id2" : {
      "2020-08-11 17:23:34" : {
        "0": "5"
      }
    },
    "id3" : {
      "2020-08-11 09:38:53" : {
        "0": "4"
      }
    },
    "id4" : {
      "2020-08-11 13:41:30" : {
        "0": "2"
      },
      "2020-08-11 13:41:44" : {
        "0": "3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I want to get all ids and write them into a column of the csv-file.
The 'test'-entries are only a placeholder for other data-entries.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function downloadData(){
    var db = firebase.database().ref();
    var dbRef = db.child('records');
    
    dbRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var b = [childKey, 'iwannasleep'];
            // console.log(childKey); 
            // console.log(b);

            var data = [b];
            console.log(data);



// ------------- export into csv ---------------


            var arrayHeader = ["user_id", "test"] 

            var csv = arrayHeader.join(',') + '\n';
            data.forEach( function(row) {
                csv += row.join(',');
                csv += "\n";
            });
        
            console.log(csv);

            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
            hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);;
            hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
            hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
            hiddenElement.click();
        
        });
      });
}
```

Comment: You're literally opening a file (or rather: creating a hidden element with the downloadable content) in the `forEach`. That will open a file "for each" record...

Comment: thanks a lot for your hint :) it is still not working how I want it to work but it saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As RobIII commented, you're creating a download link *inside* the for loop, which means that you're creating a separate element for each row of data.

You'll want to pull that out of the loop:

```
var db = firebase.database().ref();
var dbRef = db.child('dataRecordings');

dbRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var arrayHeader = ["user_id", "test"] 
    var csv = arrayHeader.join(',') + '\n';

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var b = [childKey, 'iwannasleep'];

        var data = [b];

        data.forEach(function(row) {
            csv += row.join(',');
            csv += "\n";
        });    
    });
    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);;
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'data.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();
});
```

---

**Update**: an example of what happens with the JSON in your question:

```js
const json = {
  "records" : {
    "id1" : {
      "2020-08-11 15:40:13" : {  "0" : "5" },
      "2020-08-11 16:35:09" : { "0" : "18" }
    },
    "id2" : {
      "2020-08-11 17:23:34" : { "0": "5" }
    },
    "id3" : {
      "2020-08-11 09:38:53" : { "0": "4" }
    },
    "id4" : {
      "2020-08-11 13:41:30" : { "0": "2" },
      "2020-08-11 13:41:44" : { "0": "3" }
    }
  }
}

var arrayHeader = ["user_id", "test"] 
var csv = arrayHeader.join(',') + '\n';

Object.keys(json.records).forEach((childKey) => {
    var b = [childKey, 'iwannasleep'];

    var data = [b];

    data.forEach(function(row) {
        csv += row.join(',');
        csv += "\n";
    });    
});

console.log(csv);
```

Comment: I have tried that but now I only get the very first id and thats it. I also tried it outside the forEach function and concatenating the arrays and joining them together and so on, but I always get the same result. But thanks a lot for your hint :) it saved me a lot of time

Comment: I'm not sure what your data structure looks like, but I'm pretty sure my code didn't change anything about how the actual data is extracted. If you continue to have problem with that, edit your question to include the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I added a standalone implementation of what your code does in my answer. If you run the snippet, you should see the same output as you have locally. If that is indeed the case: what output do you expect from this input?

Comment: instead of the records I want the ids to be there. So there would be user_id, test as the header and then id1, iwannasleep in the next row, id2, iwannasleep below and so on. I know my approach has loads of errors since it's not working but I don't know what to change anymore.

Comment: I updated the code in my answer to generate the output I thikn you wnat.

Comment: oh my goodness, after a very well good night's sleep, it seems so very simple. Thank you very much :)